# MDADM RAID1 Re-assembly - Non-destructive Method?

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm

After a system reboot, my MDADM array suddenly showed very old (more than a year) data. I assume that one of the disks (sdd1) has been offline for most of that time, and after the reboot I am now seeing only that disk, not the more current disk (sdc1). Luckily both disks are intact, so I don't believe that I have lost any data. My goal is to take the old disk out of the array, then add the newer disk into the array. Once the data is verified and backed up, I would like to rebuild the array so that both disks are working as they should be.

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdd1[1]
      976630336 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>


# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Feb 27 00:29:21 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 976630336 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976630336 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Oct  4 10:55:30 2017
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : hypervisor:0  (local to host hypervisor)
           UUID : 3676c254:c804e29a:1150107a:a390f263
         Events : 12989

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1


# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1 
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 3676c254:c804e29a:1150107a:a390f263
           Name : hypervisor:0  (local to host hypervisor)
  Creation Time : Wed Feb 27 00:29:21 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1953260976 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Array Size : 976630336 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953260672 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 67dcc89f:185338b3:9724c8e6:0d437f28

    Update Time : Tue Oct  3 22:04:15 2017
       Checksum : 75e1922c - correct
         Events : 1329213


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing) 


# mdadm --examine /dev/sdd1 
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 3676c254:c804e29a:1150107a:a390f263
           Name : hypervisor:0  (local to host hypervisor)
  Creation Time : Wed Feb 27 00:29:21 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1953260976 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Array Size : 976630336 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953260672 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 56c78b79:a587561c:07e7785e:9c6845e2

    Update Time : Wed Oct  4 10:55:30 2017
       Checksum : ea2a38e7 - correct
         Events : 12989


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Note that the "Events" count of sdc1 is much higher than sdd1. Also note that none of the disks are shown as failed, however one of the disks (sdc1) is shown as removed.

After I have backed up sdc and sdd, am I safe to do the following:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdd1
mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdd1
mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdc1
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need unplug sdd drive and try to boot on sdc  drive.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't setfaulty+remove the single drive of an array.

Best would be to take out `sdd` and put in `sdc`. Perhaps it's auto detected, perhaps not (since the drive is not included as it is right now).

There are `mdadm` commands you can do to take the current array offline and bring the array with `sdc` online, but because they probably have the same GUIDs, that may be hard.

I really wonder what happened here, BTW. Perhaps `sdc` doesn't have `raid-autodetect` partitions? What does `fdisk -lu /dev/sdc` show?

Comment: # fdisk -lu /dev/sdc

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 382818 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  1953525167   976761560   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Comment: @user438320 I can't read that. Edit your question and put it in there, *as a code block*.